# Ubuntu 18.04 configure Terminator Shell

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I can use the default terminal on Ubuntu for software development but prefer Terminator.

On Ubuntu 16.04, I just installed Terminator and it ran the same way as the normal terminal but on Ubuntu 18.04, I installed Terminator but it seems to default to the bash shell that keeps giving me **Permission denied**.

I tried `Preferences -> Profile -> Command` and checked both **Run command as a login shell** and **Run a custom command instead of my shell**.

Then put `/bin/sh` in the window and "Hold the terminal open." 
This gives me just a "$ " prompt and the same **Permission denied** response to sudo and the title bar still has `/bin/bash`

What am I doing wrong?